# Nodejs/Expressjs POST requests limited — affected by localhost firewall / security policies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, networking

I have a frontend script that takes a value from an HTML button and passes it to the backend. It works just fine, except that if the button is clicked repeatedly to send a bunch of POST requests to the backend, only about seven or eight pass through before the rest show up as *Pending* in the browser's element inspect.

Is this an issue with the code, or is this to be expected as some kind of port filtering mechanism in the network?

Frontend:

```
async function submitCity(){
    let x = document.getElementById("wg_input").value;
    console.log("Successfully captured city name:", x);
    let toWeather = JSON.stringify({city: x});
    console.log("Input data successfully converted to JSON string:", toWeather);
    
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: toWeather
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:3000', options)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Server.js:

```
// Dependencies

const express = require('express');
const bp = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const jimp = require('jimp');
const cors = require('cors');
const wgServer = express();
const port = 3000;

// Dotenv package

require("dotenv").config();

// OpenWeatherMap API_KEY

const apiKey = `${process.env.API_KEY}`;

// Basic server initialization

wgServer.use(cors())
wgServer.use(bp.json())
wgServer.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

wgServer.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});

wgServer.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  console.log(req.body);
  let preclean = req.body;
  console.log(preclean);
  //const data = await req.body;
  // let jsonData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
 // res.status(201);
  //res.json();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the browser queuing those requests until one of the previous ones finishes.

Browsers have a limit to how many simultaneous requests they will send to the same host.  Once you hit that limit, they queue subsequent requests until one of the previous requests finishes at which point they will send the next one in the queue.

This wouldn't have anything to do with filtering in the network.

Comment: Got it, but those requests remain in pending indefinitely, until I either refresh the page, or restart the server. Same principle?

Comment: @JeremyMarino - Are they never reaching your server at all?  Or is your server never sending a response, thus the client is still waiting for a response?  The code you show for `wgServer.post("/", ...)` has the sending of a response commented out.  You MUST send an http response to every single http request your server receives.  Otherwise these http sockets get "stuck" and eventually either client or server will time them out.